# Dictionary causes index out of range error in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Sorry if this is asked already but I haven't found a solution for it. I'm new to Swift so please bear with me. I can't figure out why I keep getting an error of **Thread 1: Fatal Error: Index out of range**. I've used the same method before in displaying a txt file to which I never got a problem with before so this is the first time. I'm trying to display coordinates as the text details with the date and time as text in the cells itself.

`Date and Time`

`Latitude, Longitude`

Something like the above (Imagine it in a cell)

The following is my code for the program

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



//Array to store the list
var storeCoordinates = [String:  String]()
var arrayClient = NSMutableArray()
var readings: [String] = [" "]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    //Get path of where the file is
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gps_coords", ofType: "csv")

    //Use filemanager to check if the file exist to avoid crashing if it doesn't exist
    let fileMgr = FileManager.default

    //Display the number of line counts we have
    if fileMgr.fileExists(atPath: path!){
        do {
            let fulltext = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            readings = fulltext.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]

            for i in 0..<readings.count{
                let listData = readings[i].components(separatedBy: ";") as [String]

                storeCoordinates["Latitude"] = "\(listData[0])"
                storeCoordinates["Longitude"] = "\(listData[1])"
                storeCoordinates["DateAndTime"] = "\(listData[2])"

                arrayClient.add(storeCoordinates)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    self.title = "Number of entries: \(arrayClient.count)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayClient.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let client = arrayClient[indexPath.row] as AnyObject

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(client.object(forKey: "DateAndTime")!)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(client.object(forKey: "Latitude")!) \(client.object(forKey: "Longitude")!)"

    return cell

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

}

The error I had is on `storeCoordinates["Latitude"] = "\(listData[0])"`
Using breakpoints, it shows the Latitude value is not empty along with Longitude and DateAndTime but if I try to run the app in the simulator, it gives the error **Thread 1: Fatal Error: Index out of range**. So far no luck in trying to figure out how to fix this. If you could help me figure it out, it would mean a lot to me. Please and thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure the app cannot crash on the line you have mentioned.  It can crash on the following line easily if you have incorrect CSV data. E.g. a blank line in the end would cause that. If you are using debugger, break on the crash and print the contents of `listData`.

Comment: Are the CSV fields really separated by comma? By the way, CSV is the worst *data base* text format. I highly recommend to use JSON or Property List. And don't misuse String Interpolation for values which are `String` anyway. And don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all.

Comment: Well, I would also call abuse the way he is using `NSMutableArray` and dictionaries with string keys instead of a `struct`.

Comment: Debug! Pause after `let listData = ...` and see what `listData` now _is_. Solve it yourself.

Comment: May be in some case `readings[i].components(separatedBy: ";")` returned `nil` or `empty array`, and thats why fetching object at 0 index will crash. You can use `if-let` for that.

Comment: @Sulthan It has an empty line at the end of the list. Just checked it using NSLog. Other than that, it does display the list accordingly to the csv file

Comment: @vadian It's separated by Semicolon. I know it's a bad format but the entry isn't that much and I was given the data in that format. So can't do much there. I'll change the `NSMutable..`

Comment: But you already wrote the code to convert CSV to a JSON or property list compliant array. Just encode the converted array to JSON or Property List, write the data to disk and use that in your project. A file in the bundle is supposed to be created in the most efficient format. Another redundant line is the `fileExists` check. The file must exist at build time and cannot be changed at runtime. A failure is a **design** error and must not occur after testing the app.

Comment: @vadian Didn't know about fileExists being a redundant line. I'll keep it in mind and learn how to convert the array to a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regard the unreliable CSV format as the origin of the issue.

This is a quick tutorial to use a better format (JSON) and a more robust data source.

## Part 1: Convert CSV to JSON

1. Create a new Blank Playground (press <kbd>⌥⇧⌘N</kbd>) platform **macOS**
2. Press <kbd>⌘0</kbd> to show the project navigator of the Playground.
3. <kbd>⌥-drag</kbd> the CSV file from the project navigator of the main project into the `Resources` folder of the Playground.
4. Paste the following code into the Playground, it's based on your code to parse the CSV. It converts the CSV to JSON and creates a file `gps_coords.json` on the desktop. You'll get a fatal error if any field is missing.

   ```
   struct Coordinate : Encodable {
       let latitude, longitude, dateAndTime : String
   }

   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gps_coords", withExtension: "csv")!
   let fulltext = try! String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
   let lines = fulltext.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
   let coordinates = lines.map { paragraph -> Coordinate in
       let components = paragraph.components(separatedBy: ";")
       if components.count != 3 { fatalError("Each line must contain all three fields")}
       return Coordinate(latitude: components[0], longitude: components[1], dateAndTime: components[2])
   }
   do {
       let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(coordinates)
       let homeURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
       let destinationURL = homeURL.appendingPathComponent("Desktop/gps_coords.json")
       try data.write(to: destinationURL)
   } catch { print(error) }
   ```

## Part 2: Implement the new file

1. Close the Playground. It's not needed anymore.
2. Drag the new file from the desktop into the project navigator (make sure `Copy If Needed` is checked).
3. Change the `ViewController` class to

   ```
   import UIKit
   import MapKit

   struct Coordinate : Decodable {
       let latitude, longitude, dateAndTime : String
   }

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

       var arrayClient = [Coordinate]()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gps_coords", withExtension: "json")!
           let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
           arrayClient = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Coordinate].self, from: data)
           self.title = "Number of entries: \(arrayClient.count)"
           tableView.reloadData()
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return arrayClient.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
           let client = arrayClient[indexPath.row]

           cell.textLabel?.text = client.dateAndTime
           cell.detailTextLabel?.text = client.latitude + " " + client.longitude
           return cell           
       }
   }
   ```

   **Note:** The `UITableView` outlet is missing and I added the line to reload the data. Make also sure that `delegate` and `datasource` is connected in Interface Builder from the table view to the `ViewController`.
4. Delete the CSV file.

The new code uses a struct `Coordinate` as data source and decodes the JSON very conveniently with `JSONDecoder`. Please note the missing type casts and the cumbersome key subscription to get the values from the dictionary.

Comment: I found the problem of it not populating. You mentioned that `delegate` and `datasource` needs to be connected in the Interface Builder. That is what was wrong. I didn't connect it. Now the table is populated so I'm selecting your answer because it looks more clean. Can't believe I forgot that one simple thing. With the **Index out of range** I changed from NSMutableArray to Swift based array. Now I just need to fix the text that has optional eg. `Optional(Latitude)`

Comment: I am because it looks clean. Thanks for all the help. :D

Comment: Part 2 / 2 You have to drag the created JSON file from the desktop into the project navigator.

Comment: Getting an error **couldn't be saved in the folder 'Desktop'.**

Comment: Did you follow **all** steps carefully? A **macOS** Playground can save in the desktop folder.

Comment: I saved the playground file directly to desktop. Now it's saying the json file doesn't exist? What?

Comment: Is the file in the project navigator and has it been **copied**? Is the Target Membership checkbox checked?

Comment: My bad. Couldnt figure out what you meant by platform. That was the problem. Got it working now. Thanks again.

Comment: Everything works well now without any optionals! Thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment, mentioned by **@vadian**, It is not possible that you didn't get 0th index. But you add some checks.

**Update your code as following:**

Some updates are -

> Use swift based array `[[String: String]]` rather `NSMutableArray`
>
> Initialize the `storeCoordinates` for each loop cycle and check if your `listData` have more than 3 items or not

```
class AViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    //Array to store the list
    var arrayClient = [[String: String]]()
    var readings: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Get path of where the file is
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gps_coords", ofType: "csv")
        
        //Use filemanager to check if the file exist to avoid crashing if it doesn't exist
        let fileMgr = FileManager.default
        
        //Display the number of line counts we have
        if fileMgr.fileExists(atPath: path!){
            do {
                let fulltext = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                
                readings = fulltext.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]
                
                for i in 0..<readings.count {
                    // Check if you can get data from `readings[i]`
                    let listData = readings[i].components(separatedBy: ";") as [String]
                    if listData.count == 3 {
                        var storeCoordinates = [String: String]()
                        storeCoordinates["Latitude"] = "\(listData[0])"
                        storeCoordinates["Longitude"] = "\(listData[1])"
                        storeCoordinates["DateAndTime"] = "\(listData[2])"
                        arrayClient.append(storeCoordinates)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        self.title = "Number of entries: \(arrayClient.count)"
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayClient.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        
        let client = arrayClient[indexPath.row]
        if let dateTime = client["DateAndTime"], let latitude = client["DateAndTime"], let longitude = client["DateAndTime"] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(dateTime)"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(latitude) \(longitude)"
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you never get `nil` because everything is non-optional,  and you never get an empty array because even an empty string returns an array with one item (empty string).

Comment: Yes @vadian, you are right. My attention wasn't on that part. I edited the answer

Comment: also, you can simply iterate over `for reading in readings {` Technically, you don't even need a `for`, it could be done with a `arrayClient = readings.compactMap { let listData = ...; guard listData.count == 3 else { return nil }  return ... }`

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Not using `NSMutableArray` did help on removing the error but it's still not populating the cell with the data.